# Coding a SwiftUI button to trigger a Menu item

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-button, swiftui-menu

I am trying to design a button in swiftUI that will call 1 of the built in menu items (mac only). I know how to replace built in menu item & force it to share the same functionality with a button, but that is not what I want to do. I wish to click the button for, let's say, Copy or Help & have the button (somehow) trigger or programmatically click the menu item itself. It need not display the menu, just run the item. This would be most useful in setting up a contextual menu or convenience button the only purpose of which is to mimic these menu items. I have hunted high & low with little success. Can anyone point me in the right direction or offer a thought or two?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to add a button with an action that will select the mac help menu item.